# How to visualize higher correlation between replicates within the control than with the treatment samples?

Tags: r, correlation, pca

The treatment which I have applied to my samples did not cause much changes comparing to the control samples. I have prepared 4 replicates for the control and 4 replicates for a treatment. I would like to show that control replicates cluster together and treatment replicates together (if it is a case). The idea is to show that samples within the control and treatment have the higher correlation than the replicates between two conditions.

I was thinking about performing PCA analysis but the way I visualized it it could not be visible. Do you have any other ideas ?

That's a part of my data:

```
structure(c(368113, 87747.35, 508620.5, 370570.5, 87286.5, 612728, 
55029, 358521, 2802880, 2045399.5, 177099, 317974.5, 320687.95, 
6971292.55, 78949, 245415.95, 50148.5, 67992.5, 97634, 56139.5, 
115443, 6003281.3525, 129951.25, 462699.7, 115724.5, 211280.35, 
340078, 100998.5, 12987.85, 12416123.5, 1933116.25, 208809.5, 
108410, 53615, 1187046, 233271.5, 14552039.5, 167108.5, 41355.85, 
475950.5, 371719.2, 80182.7, 612078.5, 367822.5, 80691, 665190.65, 
28283.5, 309720, 2853241.5, 1584324, 135482.5, 270959, 343879.1, 
6748208.5, 71534.9, 258976, 28911.75, 78306, 56358.7, 46783.5, 
128617.5, 5459280.9505, 131973, 559920.05, 138396, 200428.05, 
243862, 127636.5, 12770.2, 12520505, 1957545.855, 176416, 80323.7, 
89284, 1228040, 188070, 12738541.65, 136589, 34079.15, 436073, 
320882.85, 53098.3, 537383.5, 404505.5, 89759.7, 624120.55, 40406, 
258183.5, 3144610.45, 1735583.5, 122013.5, 249741, 362585.35, 
5383869.15, 23172.2, 223704.45, 40543.7, 68522.5, 43187.05, 29745, 
128234.5, 5356390.0645, 122999.15, 562653.05, 98135.5, 161176.95, 
246434.7, 132517.5, 12933.9, 13065545, 1811097.15, 156342, 79270.5, 
107529.6, 1227671.5, 184533.5, 13564471.5, 140331, 47301.55, 
462244, 356058.5, 89287.25, 492242.5, 452135.5, 97253.55, 575661.95, 
65739.5, 334703.5, 3136065, 1622936.5, 131381.5, 254362, 311496.3, 
5627561, 68210.6, 264610.1, 45851, 65010.5, 32665.5, 39957.5, 
86404, 6291560.39, 104597, 494811.05, 120070.5, 203246.6, 347566, 
175749.5, 12591.9, 13387541.5, 1642647.25, 186852, 70971, 45292.5, 
1166752, 254120, 13743050.7, 157161.5, 33182.55, 406996.5, 362476.75, 
59451.65, 548279, 345096.5, 93363.5, 596444.2, 11052.5, 252812, 
2934035, 1732707.55, 208409.5, 208076.5, 437764.25, 16195882.45, 
77461.25, 205803.85, 30437.5, 75540, 49576.75, 48878, 113419, 
6555248.7515, 66550.5, 551912.35, 95386, 204104.95, 349818, 101726.5, 
13143.7, 13415850, 1978511.415, 204598.5, 88502.5, 33084, 1142965, 
203408, 13812755, 167146.5, 52139.2, 453975.5, 340380.5, 43785.35, 
482713, 340315, 64308.5, 517859.85, 11297, 268993.5, 3069028.5, 
1571889, 157561, 217596.5, 400610.65, 5703337.6, 50640.65, 197477.75, 
40070, 66619, 81564.55, 41436.5, 128300.5, 6223621.376, 74440, 
472732.1, 96015, 140582.2, 329933, 150337.5, 13463.75, 12879070.5, 
2295360.75, 234709.5, 63521.5, 72558, 1138540, 188351, 13227163.5, 
158380, 40913, 526715.5, 367592.3, 64954.9, 530093, 432025, 87212.5, 
553901.65, 20803.5, 333940.5, 3027254.5, 1494468, 195221, 222895.5, 
494429.45, 7706885.75, 60633.35, 192827.1, 29857.5, 81001.5, 
112588.65, 68904.5, 110674, 6461798.509, 77332.5, 392572, 109108, 
140622.5, 451441, 283180, 11261.6, 12344087.5, 1897865.4, 334157, 
83969, 80366.5, 1107063.5, 257995, 14698440.8, 166238.5, 44926.95, 
393584, 338822.5, 56868.15, 467350, 314526.5, 105568, 749456.1, 
19597.5, 298939.5, 2993199.2, 1615231.5, 229185.5, 280433.5, 
360156.15, 5254889.1, 79369.5, 175434.05, 40907.05, 70919, 65720.15, 
53054.5, 122125.5, 7419325.08, 76741, 601393, 88776, 190919.55, 
373276.5, 174840.5, 19115.1, 14394779.5, 1837206.1, 238701, 72535.5, 
92102.5, 1137987, 245086.5, 13690206.9, 174625.5, 49742.5, 428403.5
), .Dim = c(40L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(c("Anne", "Greg", "thomas", 
"Chris", "Gerard", "Monk", "Mart", "Mutr", "Aeqe", "Tor", "Gaer", 
"Toaq", "Kolr", "Wera", "Home", "Terlo", "Kulte", "Mercia", "Loki", 
"Herta", "MadAnne", "MadGreg", "Madthomas", "MadChris", "MadGerard", 
"MadMonk", "MadMart", "MadMutr", "MadAeqe", "MadTor", "MadGaer", 
"MadToaq", "MadKolr", "MadWera", "MadHome", "MadTerlo", "MadKulte", 
"MadMercia", "MadLoki", "MadHerta"), c("Day_Rep1", "Day_Rep2", 
"Day_Rep3", "Day_Rep4", "Night_Rep1", "Night_Rep2", "Night_Rep3", 
"Night_Rep4")))
```

Each of the column is a replicate. First 4 are the control replicates and next 4 are from treatment samples. I would like to show that rows from the first four columns are together and rows from last 4 columns belong together.

I think that it should be like that. If not... I have to show it anyway :).

PCA analysis ? Tree cluster ?

Comment: Is it possible to perform tree cluster to visualize it ?